# Valgrind: understanding output (HEAP SUMMARY is ok, ERROR SUMMARY is confusing)

Tags: memory, memory-leaks, heap-memory, valgrind

I read a number of messages on this topic but this is a little different because I have NO heap errors (I cleaned everything up nicely - yay).  But, I still see 166 errors in the error summary.

My question is:
1. Is this a problem in *MY CODE* or in libraries/system stuff
2. My program is a service which will run for years (hopefully) nonstop.  Are these 166 errors a concern that my program will cause an eventual memory leak?

```
==1758== 
==1758== HEAP SUMMARY:
==1758==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==1758==   total heap usage: 3,658 allocs, 3,658 frees, 4,561,685 bytes allocated
==1758== 
==1758== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==1758== 
==1758== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==1758== ERROR SUMMARY: 166 errors from 13 contexts (suppressed: 6 from 6)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. pls show how you run valgrind, i mean the args
2. as the last two lines says: "For counts of detected and suppressed errors, **rerun with: -v**"
3. the error typically means a sys call return -1, eg: "close a invalid fd"
4. you had better fix all the errors if you want it to be perfect